# How to highlight a cell only if it contains the minimum value in a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am compiling a price comparison between a brands products in different online shops, of which one should have a benchmark fuction. So I have my item numbers in the first column of the spreadsheet, and my benchmark shop prices in the second. The following columns contain prices of the same item numbers in different shops.

I want to avoid that my benchmark shop prices are lower than any of the other shops', which is why I want to have a conditional formatting for the second column based on the condition that the value in it is the lowest in its row. I'm sure it's got to be something with "if" and "min" but I just can't figure it out...

Comment: What have you tried, what research have you done? Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Excel on Windows:

1. Select the row of cells you'd like to highlight
2. On the **Home** tab, in the **Styles** group, click the arrow next to **Conditional Formatting**, and then click **Manage Rules**. The *Conditional Formatting Rules Manager* dialog box appears.
3. Click **New Rule**. The *New Formatting Rule* dialog box appears.
4. Under **Apply Rule To**, optionally click **Selected cells**
5. Under **Select a Rule Type**, click **Format all cells based on their values** (default).
6. Under **Edit the Rule Description**, in the **Format Style** list box, select **2-Color Scale**.
7. To select a type in the **Type** box for **Minimum** and **Maximum**, select **Lowest Value** and **Highest Value**
8. To choose a **Minimum** and **Maximum** color scale, click **Color** for each, and then select a color.

Excerpts above adopted from:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f#__toc304825859_1